# Mercurial hg merge default

Tags: mercurial, merge, rebase

I am running a rebase on a set of changes in Hg. Occasionally it comes up with a message that says something like `local changed somefile.cs which remote deleted. use (c)hanged version or (d)elete?`

I assume that when I am rebasing I want to follow what the remote is doing, so I have been deleting. If this is incorrect, someone stop me.

However, here is the big thing? I've noticed that if I just press `Enter` it seems to move on. However **I have no idea what it is defaulting to**. Does anyone know?

Comment: Also since I always pick the same options, any way to just make them happen automatically would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default is to use the `(c)hanged version`.  Rebase uses the merge logic for this operation.

There is no documentation of this default choice, but it is decided [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/1a791993ce59/mercurial/merge.py#l216):

```
   216                 if repo.ui.promptchoice(
   217                     _(" local changed %s which remote deleted\n"
   218                       "use (c)hanged version or (d)elete?") % f,
   219                     (_("&Changed"), _("&Delete")), 0):
   220                     act("prompt delete", "r", f)
   221                 else:
   222                     act("prompt keep", "a", f)
```

There does not appear to be a way to automatically decide which option is selected.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm just trying to follow a rebase along what the original changes were, I'm assuming I don't want to keep the local version if the remote deleted it. Am I at least correct there?

Comment: @jocull: Since both sides of the merge touched the file, Mercurial is trying to provide a 'safe' default which won't result in data loss.  However if you intended to delete the file in one of your rebased (i.e. remote) changesets, then you should not keep the local version.

Comment: Thanks for the code reference! `yes d | hg rebase...` was still resulting in the use of "changed" every time (eg; supplying c). Changing the `, 0` to `, 1` works! (However, I am now in doubt as to what it was doing, it might have just been saying "c" and accepting "d", but at least now both should match)